# Modificar as dimensões do ícone da largura

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde, em um site que estou desenvolvendo preciso colocar como o estilo do ícone da lista desordenada como uma imagem, mas pelo fato dela ser grande demais eu gostaria apenas de diminuir sua largura. Tentei aqui mas não consegui, segue em anexo o código.

**Html:**

```
<div class="instrucoes">
    <div class="passo1">
        <span>1.</span> <br>
        <span>Deve atender aos requisitos básicos</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Possuir CNPJ</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Se enquadrar em um dos programas apoiados pelo banco</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Pertencer a um dos municípios atendidos</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.passo1 ul{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    list-style-image: url(../images/check-gray.png);
    color: var(--fontGray);
    font-size: 14px;
}
.passo1 ul li::before {
    position: relative !important;
    display: flex !important;
    width: 20px !important;
}
.passo1 ul li, .passo2 ul li, .passo3 ul li{margin: 25px 0;}
.passo1 span{
    color: var(--fontGray) !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível controlar o tamanho da imagem usado no `list-style-image`

Minha sugestão é que já que vc colocou um `::before` na sua `li` que vc coloque a imagem nesse mesmo *pseudo-elemento*.

Veja esse exemplo, não mudei nada no seu HTML, e no CSS apenas usei o `::before` que já tinha lá para colocar a imagem e alinhar das `li`.

```css
.passo1 ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    list-style:none;
    color: var(--fontGray);
    font-size: 14px;
}
.passo1 ul li::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/60/60);
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
.passo1 ul li, 
.passo2 ul li, 
.passo3 ul li {
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.passo1 span{
    color: var(--fontGray) !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="instrucoes">
    <div class="passo1">
        <span>1.</span> <br>
        <span>Deve atender aos requisitos básicos</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Possuir CNPJ</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Se enquadrar em um dos programas apoiados pelo banco</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Pertencer a um dos municípios atendidos</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Colocar um `background` na `li` e controlar o tamanho e a posição com `background-size` e `background-position`.

*Deixei os comentários no código*

**Exiba e executa o código abaixo para ver**

```css
.passo1 ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    /* list-style-image: url(https://placecage.com/60/60); */
    color: var(--fontGray);
    font-size: 14px;
}

.passo1 ul li, 
.passo2 ul li, 
.passo3 ul li {
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding-left: 2rem;
 list-style: none;
 background-image: url(https://placecage.com/60/60);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* posição da imagem */
 background-position: left center;
  /* tamanho da imagem */
 background-size: 20px;
}
.passo1 span{
    color: var(--fontGray) !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="instrucoes">
    <div class="passo1">
        <span>1.</span> <br>
        <span>Deve atender aos requisitos básicos</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Possuir CNPJ</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Se enquadrar em um dos programas apoiados pelo banco</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Pertencer a um dos municípios atendidos</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```